# What is similar to CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK in CDC?

Tags: sql

I am working on an application to synchronize data.  We decided to use CDC in place of CT because we need more information, but at the same time we need a function which return the column which changing affects it something like this using CT:

```
SELECT 
CTTable.SYS_CHANGE_OPERATION,
[FNameCh] = CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK(COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('CONTACT_TABLE'),        
       'contact_name', 'ColumnId'), SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS),
[LNameCh] = CHANGE_TRACKING_IS_COLUMN_IN_MASK(COLUMNPROPERTY(OBJECT_ID('CONTACT_TABLE'), 
       'contact_lastname', 'ColumnId'), SYS_CHANGE_COLUMNS),

FROM CHANGETABLE (CHANGES Contacts, @VersionId) AS CTTable 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Contacts AS C ON C.CONTACT_ID = CTTable.CONTACT_ID
GO
```

EDIT:

```
SELECT * , sys.fn_cdc_has_column_changed ('dbo_CONTACT_TABLE', 'contact_name', __$update_mask) AS FNameCh 

From   cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_CONTACT_TABLE(@Start_Lsn,@End_Lsn,'all')
which 1 for if the contact_name is changed and 0 if is not.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We can identify using sys.fn_cdc_is_bit_set. Please find the link below for detailed information

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500241.aspx